# How to configure SFLPhone or other softphine with german telekom?

Tags: voip

I would like to use a softphone on my desktop. We have an telekom IP contract and they tell me it is possible to use any sip phone. I installed SFLPhone and tried to enter my credentials but it just fails.

I asked my provider, they told me the following:

```
SIP-ID/Benutzer: Ihre Telefonnummer 
Bildschirmname (falls vorhanden): Ihre Telefonnummer 
Authentifizierungs-Name / Benutzername: Ihre E-Mail-Adresse, z.B. "vorname.name@t-online.de" 
Passwort: Ihr Passwort
SIP-Proxy: tel.t-online.de 
Registrar: tel.t-online.de 
Realm: tel.t-online.de 
STUN-Server: stun.t-online.de 
Outbound-Proxy: leer lassen oder ebenfalls tel.t-online.de
```

I tried nearly every combination but I can't get connected. But I don't see why. I don't know where to put what.

Does somebody know how to debug sflphone (or other softphone on ubuntu) to see what fails exactly?

(or even better: does somebody know how to configure it with telekom IP contract?)

Answer (score 1):

You can try Ekiga instead. It has less options and probably will solve your issue.

You will only need to write your Registrar (tel.t-online.de), username, and password.

If it does not connect then try setting STUN or Proxy in Preferences.